# Manually renaming y-axis variable names in a ggplot2 facet plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I am trying to rename the labels of my independent variables on the y-axis of my ggplot2 facet plot. The original labels are simply the factor levels of my target variable column and thus contain underscores and their meanings are incomprehensible. Prior to renaming the labels as I'd like, my code looks like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat_AS_regr <- read_csv("model_performances.csv")
dat_AS_regr$target_var <- as.factor(dat_AS_regr$target_var)

target_var_category_names <- c(
  `Fraction Level` = "Fraction Level",
  `Joined Fractions Level` = "Joined Fractions Level",
  `Bulk Soil Level`  = "Bulk Soil Level")

shapes <- c(2, 5, 0)
dat_AS_regr %>% 
  filter(log_transf == 0) %>%
   mutate(target_var = fct_relevel(target_var,
     "BNC_contr_frac_MNC", "FNC_contr_frac_MNC", "MNC_contr_frac_C",
     "BNC_contr_bothfrac_bothfrac_MNC", "FNC_contr_bothfrac_bothfrac_MNC", 
     "MNC_contr_bothfrac_bothfrac_C","BNC_contr_frac_bulk_C","FNC_contr_frac_bulk_C", 
     "MNC_contr_frac_bulk_C","BNC_contr_bothfrac_bulk_C","FNC_contr_bothfrac_bulk_C", 
     "MNC_contr_bothfrac_bulk_C")) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = RMSE, y = target_var)) +
              geom_point(aes(x = RMSE, y = target_var, color = "RMSE", shape = fraction), size = 3) +
              geom_point(aes (x = MAE, y = target_var, color = "MAE", shape = fraction), size = 3) + 
              geom_point(aes(x = R_squared/0.05, y = target_var, color = "R_squared"), size = 3) +
                labs(title = "Comparing  Models' Loss Metrics", subtitle = "rPCA Stepwise Regression", 
                     x = "Loss metrics (RMSE, MAE)", y = "Target variables", color = "Model evaluation metrics", shape = "Fraction") +
                        theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
                        facet_grid(target_var_category_ordered~., labeller = as_labeller(target_var_category_names), space = "free", scales = "free") +
                          scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. *0.05, name = expression(paste(R^2)))) +
                          scale_shape_manual(values=shapes) +
                          scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
```

I tried renaming the the labels of my independent variables on the y-axis using the following additional line of code added to the rest of the code shown above:

```
scale_y_discrete(labels = c("BNC contribution of a fraction to its MNC [%]", "FNC contribution of a fraction to its MNC [%]",
                 "MNC contribution of a fraction to its C [%]", "BNC contribution of both fractions to their joined MNC [%]",
                 "FNC contribution of both fractions to their joined MNC [%]", "MNC contribution of both fractions to their joined C [%]",
                 "BNC contribution of a fraction to bulk soil C [%]", "FNC contribution of a fraction to bulk soil C [%]",
                 "MNC contribution of a fraction to bulk soil C [%]", "BNC contribution of both joined fractions to bulk soil C [%]",
                 "FNC contribution of both joined fractions to bulk soil C [%]", "MNC contribution of both joined fractions to bulk soil C [%]"))
```

This code works to rename the y-axis, as long as I don't apply the facet grid "grouping" of the y-axis target variable factor levels. In the current state when I add these lines of codes to the code shown above, the first three elements of the vector specified in scale_y_discrete are used for the first three y-axis elements of the facet labelled "Fraction Level" but the same three are also taken for the "Joined Fractions Level" facet and the first six elements of the vector are taken for the "Bulk Soil Level" facet. The plot then looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can get the elements of the vector mapped from the first to the last element of the  y-axis as I specified? Or is there a way I can individually rename the  y-axis labels of each individual facet?

Comment: I would try with a lookup table, i.e. make a named vector of labels e.g. `labels <- c(BNC_contr_frac_MNC = "BNC contribution of a fraction to its MNC [%]", FNC_contr_frac_MNC = "FNC contribution of a fraction to its MNC [%]", ...)`. You could then pass this vector to the `labels` argument of `scale_y_discrete` which should ensure that the right labels are assigned to factor levels.

Comment: This sadly doesn't work and leaves me with the same plot as shown in my image. It just also takes the first 1-3 elements of the vector for the first 3 labels of all three facets.